# How to check if a dataframe contains any string and find the location of it if it does exist in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, types, type-conversion, locate

When I try to convert a dataframe to `dtype=float`, it returns error says can't convert string to float. Thus I am trying to find the location of the string in the dataframe.

Here is a sample dataframe I created:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,25).reshape(6,4))
Attribute = ['Eric', 'Sarah', 'Steve', 'David', 'Sam', 'Joe']
df.insert(0, 'Name', Attribute)
df[2][4] = 'strin'
```

and it looks like:

```
    Name   0   1      2   3
0   Eric   1   2      3   4
1  Sarah   5   6      7   8
2  Steve   9  10     11  12
3  David  13  14     15  16
4    Sam  17  18  strin  20
5    Joe  21  22     23  24
```

By the way it raises a warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from 
a DataFrame
```

If anyone knows how to avoid the warning pls lmk too. I create an iterator to return the position of str in columns I want:

```
for x in range(2,df.shape[1]):
    for y in range(df.shape[0]):
        if type(df.iloc[:,x][y]) == str:
            print('str:',(y,x))
```

it works. returns `str: (4, 3)`. I wonder if there is a easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way if you know it's just 1 problematic string is just trying to convert with `pd.to_numeric`, the traceback contains the index:

```
>>> pd.to_numeric(df[2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1021, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric
ValueError: Unable to parse string "strin"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py", line 126, in to_numeric
    coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric)
  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1052, in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric
ValueError: Unable to parse string "strin" at position 4
```

However, I believe this would only return the first occurrence. So we can coerce errors, and find the resulting `NaN`:

```
>>> pd.to_numeric(df[2], errors='coerce').isnull()
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: 2, dtype: bool
```

Problematic string found at index 4! This would allow you to subset the DataFrame to show all the strings where conversion failed, just pass that `bool` array to a `df[]` call.

EDIT: I realised I didn't cover the case where a string could be found in multiple columns. To avoid iterating over columns you can use the following snippet to get a another bool array:

```
import functools

df.loc[0, 1] = 'another_string'

df[[0,1,2,3]].apply(functools.partial(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')).isnull().any(axis=1)

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Passing that `bool` array to a `df[]` call prints:

```
   Name   0               1      2   3
0  Eric   1  another_string      3   4
4   Sam  17              18  strin  20
```

If you want the row, column coordinates, use `np.where`:

```
results = df[[0,1,2,3]].apply(functools.partial(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')).isnull()
np.where(results)

# returns both positions: (array([0, 4], dtype=int64), array([1, 2], dtype=int64))
```

Alternatively, you could iterate over the values, try to convert to a numeric type, get the problematic string from the exception and look for it:

```
import re

r = re.compile("(?<=\')\w+(?=\')")

for row in df[2]:
    try:
        float(row)
    except ValueError as exc:
        matches = r.findall(str(exc))
        for m in matches:
            i = (df[2] == m).index
            print(f"Found string '{m}' at index {i}")

# prints:
# Found string 'strin' at index Int64Index([4], dtype='int64')
```

This just seems like over complicating things, but I wanted to try it :).

Finally, a word on the warning you're getting. The following code produces no warning:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,25).reshape(6,4))
Attribute = ['Eric', 'Sarah', 'Steve', 'David', 'Sam', 'Joe']
df.insert(0, 'Name', Attribute)
df.loc[4, 2] = 'strin' # no warning
```

When you call `df[2][4]` you're making two calls: `__getitem__(2)` and subsequently `__getitem__(4)`, what is known as [chained indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), where as `df.loc[4, 2]` is just one call. This could return either a view or a copy of your DataFrame, depending on the situation, which leads to unexpected bugs down the line. Also using a single `.loc` call could potentially be faster. Be sure to read the docs for a more detailed explanation.